# How can i make my letters if pressed appear on the user interface

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate the wordle game and a function of mine isn't working. The function was supposed to output any letter pressed to the user interface.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
let currentCount = ``;

function addLetter(letter) {

  if (currentCount.length < ANSWER_LENGTH) {
    //adds letter to the end
    currentCount += letter
  } else {
    //replaces last letter
    currentCount.length = currentCount.substring(0, currentCount.length - 1) + letter
  }
  // inputs leeter on the user interface but its not working why?
  letters[currentCount.length - 1].innerText = letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to change the length of the currentCount string, which is not possible. You should update the string itself instead.

```
let currentCount = '';

function addLetter(letter) {
    if (currentCount.length < ANSWER_LENGTH) {
        // Adds letter to the end
        currentCount += letter;
    } else {
        // Replaces last letter
        currentCount = currentCount.substring(0, currentCount.length - 1) + letter;
    }

    // Inputs letter on the user interface
    letters[currentCount.length - 1].innerText = letter;
}
```